# OpenCV configuring issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to make OpenCV run on my PC.

I have downloaded openCV version 2.4.2 and also, I have downloaded another VC++ 2010 project which used open CV.

However, in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies section, I have 4 .lib items :

- cv200d.lib
- cxcore200d.lib
- highgui200d.lib
- cvaux200d.lib

The problem is that I cannot find those in my version of openCV. They .lib items from my current openCV version have a prefix of opencv_*.lib .

Do you know why I am receiving this error? Should I replace those values with some of the new .lib items? If so, which are the correspondents?

Comment: did you use the exe to install opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV 2.0 is a very old version. Current versions are in the 2.4.x range. If you have compiled the OpenCV source code, you should have cv242d.lib ( and other 242 libs). In your project linker input, you will need to replace each of the *200* with *242*. Similarly, you will need to change your additional include path( in the C/C++ options) to point to the new include directory. If you are lucky and there is no change in API, your code should compile successfully - I think there is a good chance it will happen.

If you get compilation/linking errors, you will need to go through your project and fix errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
cv200d.lib
cxcore200d.lib
highgui200d.lib
cvaux200d.lib
```

it's a old library files - the first opencv version.
You use the second version (2.4.2) and must use opencv*.lib files instead of the files above

Comment: Are you sure that I can add `opencv*.lib` to additional dependencies? I tried this, but it outputs some errors.

Comment: Errors are in output because you have different fnc in headers and different in libs.

Comment: You should add opencv_*.lib to additional dependencies and use header files from Opencv2 directory

Answer (score 0):

Project uses older version of OpenCV. You should include new files (from your opencv2/ dir), add your libs (after compilation). Some functions might differ between version's and some code rewriting might be needed.

Another option for you is to download same version of opencv and compile it.